# Multidimensional array same value items sum quantity

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my array inside the page

http://pinaaclecloud.com/vcm/checkavail.php

in this same check_in_date and room then quantity will be sum of all matching date and room .

Please help me

Comment: [Sum elements from multimendion array by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53955018/sum-elements-from-multimendion-array-by-key) Check this, might be help you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a minimal, complete, verifiable example. stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Without it, it will be almost impossible to help you

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I assume that you want to find the total `qty` for each room, on a particular date.

```
$totals = array();
foreach($arr as $val){

  if (array_key_exists($val['room'], $totals) && array_key_exists($val['check_in_date'], $totals[$val['room']]))
  {
    $totals[$val['room']][$val['check_in_date']] += $val['qty'];
  } else {
    $totals[$val['room']][$val['check_in_date']] = $val['qty'];
  }
};

echo "<pre>";print_r($totals);
```